# AJAX Django Delete Function is Not Deleting the Object

Tags: python, json, django, ajax, function

I am trying to delete an object with a close button and it was working without using AJAX but I had to reload the page in order to reflect some changes in my methods. When I applied AJAX, it was no longer deleting.

views.py

```
elif request.method == 'DELETE':

        id = json.loads(request.body)['id']
        project = get_object_or_404(Project,id=id)
        project.delete()

        return JsonResponse('')
```

profile.html

```
<a onclick="deleteProject(this)" data-id="{{project.id}}" class="close col-sm-2" aria-label="Close">
    <span class="card-block float-right"  aria-hidden="true">&times</span>
</a>
...
<script>
    $(document).on('.close',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:'DELETE'
            url:'user/profile'
            data: {
                'id' : id
            }
            success: function deleteProject(e) {

                let id = e.dataset.id
                e.closest('li').remove()

                fetch('',{
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'id': id
                    }),
                    credentials: 'same-origin',
                })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am using AJAX with Django? It works when I just keep everything from "function deleteProject(e)..." but I don't want to have to reload the page to show how the number of projects and total budget changes. Is there a way I can fix this or maybe an alternative to using AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

> It works when I just keep everything from "function deleteProject(e)..."

There are a couple of differences with `deleteProject(e)` and `$.ajax`:

- X-CSRFToken headers
- Access Control Credentials
- Request URL
- the way the object passed in the ajax function is denoted

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = e.target.dataset.id;

  function deleteProject() {
    $(e.target).closest('li').remove();
  }

  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    },
    method: 'DELETE', // jquery v1.9.1+
    url: '/user/profile',
    data: {
      'id': id
    },
    success: deleteProject
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried this but I got an error Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteProject is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick when I checked the Chrome console. Is there something else I need to download first?

Comment: I fixed the error by adding <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" > but the delete button is still not working. Does that mean that AJAX is not downloaded?

Comment: (1) The handler wasn't being registered for the click event. (2) The dataset wasn't accessed on a event target. (3) Check that Jquery library version 1.9.1 and above is used. (4) Check the function is declared. https://jsfiddle.net/rainbowseven/tenLdm72/2/

Comment: I edited the code accordingly but it seems as though it's not entering the script because even when I added an alert nothing showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code For You

```
  $(document).on('click','.delete',function(event) {
           console.log('deleted');
           var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
           $.get('delete', {id:id}, function(response){
           var tabrow = '#table-'+id;
          $(tabrow).remove();
         });
    });
```

Check This https://github.com/gowthamand/django-crud-ajax-login-register-fileupload